# "Error installing GridDB on Ubuntu 20.04"

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, griddb

I am doing the installation of griddb server on ubuntu multiple times, but I keep getting the same error

```
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https gnupg
wget -qO - https://griddb.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/gpg/key/public | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://griddb.jfrog.io/artifactory/deb/ $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/griddb.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y griddb-c griddb-c-dev griddb-java griddb-python griddb-server
```

I am trying to install GridDB on Ubuntu 20.04 using the provided installation script, but I am encountering an error. The script runs successfully up to a point, but then I get the following error message:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project griddb-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs:griddb-core:jar:4.5.0: Failed to collect dependencies at com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs:griddb-c-client:jar:4.5.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs:griddb-c-client:jar:4.5.0: Could not transfer artifact com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs:griddb-c-client:pom:4.5.0 from/to GridDB-Community (https://griddb.jfrog.io/griddb/GridDB-Community): Connection reset -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

Try this method instead: https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/using-apt/

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://www.griddb.net/apt griddb/5.1 multiverse" >>  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/griddb.list'
$ wget -qO - https://www.griddb.net/apt/griddb.asc | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install griddb-meta
```