# Griddb not installing on Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-22.04, griddb

I have been trying to install Griddb on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and I keep getting an error. The installation does not complete and it seems to be placing a lock on certain system files. I have followed the guide provided on their guide [here](https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/using-apt/#user-and-directory-structure-after-installation), both the video and the blog instructions but I don't seem to get past the sudo update command. I did also try the answer recommended [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76148812/error-installing-griddb-on-ubuntu-20-04) but it didn't work in my case. Any assistance is appreciated.

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://www.griddb.net/apt griddb/5.3 multiverse" >>  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/griddb.list'
$ wget -qO - https://www.griddb.net/apt/griddb.asc | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install griddb-meta
```

I cannot get past the above commands to finish up the installation as this is where it breaks.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the installation issue. It turns out that I had to restart my computer. From then on I proceeded with the remaining commands. So basically you have to do:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://www.griddb.net/apt griddb/5.3 multiverse" >>  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/griddb.list'
$ wget -qO - https://www.griddb.net/apt/griddb.asc | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt update
```

Restart your system (if the error occurs) and then proceed to do:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install griddb-meta
```

To start the your GridDB server

```
$ sudo systemctl start gridstore
```

More info you can find in their [GriddB installation guide](https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/using-apt/#install-with-apt-get)